# Working out Percentages whilst leaving out blank entries

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `feedback`, to monitor feedback from an event:

```
id, heardabout, booking
0   friend      0
1   online      5
2   friend      3
```

And i've been using this query to work out the percentages for them:

```
SELECT `booking` AS `rating`, (COUNT(`booking`) * 100 / (Select COUNT(*) FROM `feedback`)) AS `percent` FROM `feedback` GROUP BY `booking`;
```

Which produces:

```
rating, percent
0       10.1449
3       5.7971
4       13.0435
5       71.0145
```

Which is fine, and correct.  However I don't want to count the '0' entries for certain fields (this means they weren't applicable to the user)  How would I go about doing that?  Simply adding `WHERE`booking`!= '0'` to the above query doesn't achieve anything but leave it out, the numbers don't change and consequently they don't add up to 100.

Comment: Provide your expected result set may better if you can provide http://sqlfiddle.com/ demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference, I actually solved this:

The SQL statement I needed was:

```
SELECT `booking` AS `rating`, 
(COUNT(`booking`) * 100 / (Select COUNT(*) FROM `feedback` WHERE `booking` != '0')) AS `percent` 
FROM `feedback`  WHERE `booking` != '0' GROUP BY `booking`;
```

The key was putting the WHERE condition within the sub-query `SELECT COUNT (*)` (and also on the end).  This means that the total to divide by is given **without** the '0' entries.